# Set dynamically rows of a table in Lightning

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience, lightning-apps, lightning-datatable

I am new to Lightning, and I would like to create a table that I could set (by a picklist) the number of rows that will appear. I have tried to put the number of rows by default, setting on the attribute **indexVar** the number of the rows, but there is no effect (it is showing all values). This is the code of the table.

```
<aura:attribute name="indx" type="Integer" default="5" /> 
<aura:iteration items="{!v.adressList}" var="dir" indexVar="{!v.indx}"> 
<tr>
     <td><div class="slds-truncate" title="{!dir.FE_sales_Country__c}">
          {!dir.FE_sales_Country__c}</div></td>
     <td><div class="slds-truncate" title="{!dir.FE_Sales_City__c}">
          {!dir.FE_Sales_City__c}</div></td>
     <td><a href="{!'/one/one.app?#/sObject/'+ dir.Street__c + '/view'}" 
          target="_blank">{!dir.Street__r.Name}</a></td>
</tr> 
</aura:iteration>
```

The code of the picklist is the next one (I still have to do `doAction` to set the value of the rows, I guess that I should just set the value to the `indx` attribute):

```
<lightning:select name="mySelect" label="Select an option:" aura:id="mySelect" value="{!v.rowValue}" onchange="{!c.doAction}">                
   <aura:iteration items="{!v.rowoptions}" var="item" >
         <option text="{!item.label}" value="{!item.value}" selected="{!item.selected}"/>
   </aura:iteration>                
</lightning:select>
```

And in the controller I have put this code:

```
loadRowOptions: function (component, event, helper) {
    var opts = [
        { value: "5", label: "5" },
        { value: "10", label: "10" },
        { value: "25", label: "25" },
        { value: "50", label: "50" }
     ];
     component.set("v.rowoptions", opts);
}
```

So I think the main problem is that I am not able to just show the number of rows that I want.

Comment: If you mix the parts of your code like this we can't understand anything. However, what I do understand is that you misunderstood the way the `indexVar` attribute works. In fact, this is an output attribute. You can't have control on it. The iteration will loop through your collection and you'll be able to know the current index using the `indexVar` attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's simply not what `indexVar` does on [`<aura:iteration>`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_tag_iteration.htm):

> `indexVar`    String  The variable name to use for the index of each item inside the iteration.

It stores on each loop iteration the current index in the row array.

You can control the number of rows you display by manipulating the content of `v.adressList`, which the iteration component is using to generate its rows. If you're trying to implement pagination, you should be setting that value to a selected sub-set of your backing data store, based upon the value of `mySelect`.